# Codeigniter database query to compare two values

Tags: php

I want to compare two values in where condition by codeigniter query.

Please help me as soon is possible.

```
<?php
$This->db->select('$a');

$This->db->where('a',$a and 'b','$b');

$This->db->from('tab');

$get = $this->db->get();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$This->db->select('$a');
$cond = array(
           'a'=> $a,
           'b'=>$b
     );
$This->db->where($cond);

$This->db->from('tab');

$get = $this->db->get();

?>
```

when you want to more than one condition in where clause you have to use associative array as per codeigniter active class refer the codeigniter docs for more information.